# Show one imagem using graphicImage

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I´m  trying to show one image that can be stored in memory on in one folder, firts I´m trying to show the content on the folder...

I´m calling a `dialog` with a `commandbutton` and inside in the `dialog` there is a `graphicImage`

But it didn´t show the image.

So whats wrong?

```
<p:dialog header="#{lbl['LABEL.ATENDENTE.IMAGEMCERTIFICADO']}" widgetVar="dlgViewCpfImagem" modal="true" resizable="false" closable="false" dynamic="true">
   <h:form id="formDlgViewCpfImagem" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p:messages id="messageDlgViewCpfImagem" showDetail="true"/>
    <p:panelGrid styleClass="noBorders panelGridCenter gridNoBackground">
      <p:row>
            <p:column>
        <p:graphicImage value="#{atendenteBean.fileCpf.getAbsolutePath()}"/>
        </p:column>
     </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
  </h:form>
  <center>
  <p:commandButton process="@this" value="#{lbl['BOTAO.FECHAR']}" oncomplete="dlgViewCpfImagem.hide()" update=":form:panelAnexarArquivo"/>
  </center>
</p:dialog>


<p:column rendered="#{not empty atendenteBean.pojo.imgCpf}">
     <p:commandButton process="@this" icon="botaoLog" styleClass="botaoImagem" oncomplete="dlgViewCpfImagem.show()"/>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to show a file point to where it is stored in your file system. That won't work unless you use **Dynamic Image Streaming**. See the example below:

**Managed Bean**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DynamicImageController {

    private StreamedContent graphicImage;

    public DynamicImageController() {
        try {
            //The image file you want to show
            File file = new File("d:\\image.png");
            InputStream is = FileUtils.openInputStream(file);
            graphicImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "image/png");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public StreamedContent getGraphicImage() {
        return graphicImage;
    }

}
```

PS: I use a session scoped bean because I want it to be simple. You should think about a more sophisticate mechanism to avoid storing too much data in session. Remember that the image tag uses a different http connection and ViewScoped beans might not be a good choice for this.

**The View**

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{dynamicImageController.graphicImage}" />
```

Comment: but there is a problem, because the project is a system that save image from clients, so it will be in the root directory of the server...

I can´t copy the file to a stream and handle?